# SQL - Best practice to refer two different table primary keys with the same foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a table Auction. Each auction can be handled from a Tribunal or a Court of Appeal.

So I have table Court of Appeal (primary key `id`):

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| C001 | Court of Appeal of Nevada |
| C002 | Court of Appeal of California |

and table Tribunal (primary key `id`):

| id | name | related_court_of_appeal_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T001 | Tribunal of San Francisco | C002 |
| T002 | Tribunal of Los Angeles | C002 |
| T003 | Tribunal of Las Vegas | C001 |

Each court of appeal can group many tribunals, in the sense that a court of appeal has higher importance than a tribunal in the law system.

Each auction in the table Auction (primary key `tribunal_or_court_id, auction_id`) can be handled either from a Tribunal or directly from a Court of Appeal if the auction has some peculiar requisites.

| tribunal_or_court_id | auction_id | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C001 | 000 | Auction #1 |
| T002 | 000 | Auction #2 |
| T002 | 001 | Auction #3 |

I need to reference the Tribunal and Court of Appeal `id` columns inside the `tribunal_or_court_id`.

I tried to define two foreign keys between `Auction.tribunal_or_court_id` and `Tribunal.id and Court.id` respectively. But it did not work since I cannot insert an auction that has a corresponding tribunal id but a not corresponding court id (and vice versa).

I thought about inserting another table populated with all of the ids from Tribunal and Court of Appeal tables, and referring to this new table inside Auction. But that is poor DB design.

What is best practice?

Comment: Personally I will approach this problem by introducing `two different nullable foreign` `keys` to the Auction table. One for `tribunal_id` and one for `court_id`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you represent inheritance in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579079/how-can-you-represent-inheritance-in-a-database)

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [mre] [ask] [Help]

Comment: [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible: `FOREIGN KEY` can point to only one table.

So, you can have two columns `tribunal_id` and `court_id`, nullable, and two foreign keys for these columns.

Complex `Primary key` constraint can not be created for nullable columns. You can use `UNIQUE` constraint instead. And synthetic PK, or no PK at all, only `UNIQUE`

Comment: Yep, two columns, two foreign keys, and a check constraint to ensure that always one of the two IDs is null and the other not.

Comment: `check (num_nulls(tribunal_id, court_id) = 1)`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you add an `institution` attribute to the `auction` table, not NULL with values `'T'` for tribunal and `'C'` for court of appeal (this design does violate 3NF though). Then

```
SELECT <..your expression list here, maybe using COALESCE..>
FROM auction a
left outer join court_of_appeal coa on a.tribunal_or_court_id = coa.id 
                                   and a.institution = 'C'
left outer join tribunal t on a.tribunal_or_court_id = t.id 
                          and a.institution = 'T';
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the auction table and left outer join the other two. After joining, use `COALESCE` to return the first non-null value of either the tribunal or court value. Since you'll only get one value or the other, it doesn't matter which order you display it in.

I'm using the name for this example:

```
SELECT COALESCE(coa.name, t.name) as tribunal_court_name
FROM auction a
left outer join court_of_appeal coa on a.tribunal_or_court_id = coa.id 
left outer join tribunal t on a.tribunal_or_court_id = t.id;
```

[COALESCE Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp)